# Low memory condition , cluster under pressure

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am constantly getting errors like 'Low memory condition , cluster under pressure' , 'bad allocation' even for simple metadata commands like `.show table extents` or `.show operations`. Nothing significant is running on the cluster , is it possible that memory is blocked from some operation that got finished sometime earlier? If so, is there any command to flush , free this reserved memory? The cluster is using V3 engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not expected, please open a support ticket.